# how to regist python function in a class as udf of sparksql

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Here is my problem:

I have a class with some functions for nlp processing and also i have to use sparksql dataframe to deal with this problems

## here is an example

```
class nlpcut:

    def __init__(self,content):
         self.content = content

    @staticmethod
    def __spark_session(filePath)：
        filePath = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').master('yarn').getOrCreate()
        dataFrameReader = session.read
        data = dataFrameReader.option('header','true') \
                              .option('inferSchema',value=True) \
                              .csv(filePath)
        return data

     def __nlp_cut(self):
         # processing some nlp cut..
         cut = nlp.cut(self.content)

         return cut

     def spark_nlp_cut(self):

         # here i want to use sparksql UDF 
         data_session = DPP().__spark_session('/project/test.csv')

         # i have problem at this part, how can i insert column 'address' content into class self.content in to class DPP?

         my_udf = udf(DPP.__nlp_cut, StringType())

         data_session.select('address',my_udf('address').alias('address_cut')).show()
```

is there any methods to put the column "address" from sparkSQL dataFrame in to class as global value which insert into the udf function as self.content?
thanks

Comment: Why do you need to store it in a class field (`self.content`)? You can add a `content` parameter to `__nlp_cut` and `address` value will be passed to it when UDF is invoked.

Comment: @SergeyKhudyakov thanks for the reply, just think a possible way to regist udf function as class it seems impossible? right? sometimes i want to use global variable in class to handle all the process....

Comment: it _is_ possible to use a class within a UDF but it still has to be a function that takes a column value as a parameter, assigns it to `self.content` (or creates an instance of nlpcut), and then calls other object methods. But keep in mind that it will be a new instance of the class _per each row_. In other words, you won't be able to see `self.content` outside of the UDF.

Comment: Also, you're trying to invoke _a static method_ from an instance (`DPP().__spark_session`) and then refer to _an instance method_ from a class  `DPP.__nlp_cut`, so it will be an unbounded method.